# javascript code to perform validation on select option?

Tags: javascript, html, select, alert

I need some javascript code to validate a select option. Means something like this.
Select Country : --select--
If the user submits the form without selecting country. we have to make a alert him saying
"please select the country".
Let me know how to do this and any sample code appreciatable
Thanks in Advance,
Laxman Chowdary

Comment: Please check this URL--> http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/validate-form-onchange-t18556.html

Comment: That url info is not related to my requirement. Once the user doesn't select the select option and form submitting only we have to alert him..

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I actually sent the same code to my friend and asked here. But not edited.That is the problem. Once again sorry for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping

> value=""

of the property you can validate it..

Answer (score 0):

try onClick event of jQuery, and just add an alert first for you to see how it works whenever that dropdown is being clicked.

Comment: Hi bunsichi, I need to work on struts1.3.8 and html with javascript.I'm not aware of Jquery. so kindly tell me in javascript.